# What is variance in coefficient in linear regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I would like to know why such uncertainty exists in linear regression exists? Why the parameters (or the regression coefficients) estimated can't be of certainty? 
Why there exist uncertainty such that we need to quantify the variance in coefficients? Where does such uncertainty comes from? Does it means the coefficients estimated with a particular linear regression model may vary across different samples from the same population so we need to quantify them?
Does there exist a mathematical explanation as of why the uncertainty arises?

Thanks.

Comment: please leave the explanation of how to quantify the variance, I know how.

Comment: there is uncertainty because you are modeling statistical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the reasons for this:

1. You have a sample, not a whole population. You are estimating the population parameters from the sample statistics, so, of course, you might be wrong. Your sample won't be a perfect representation of the population.
2. Your model isn't complete. This is a good thing. "All models are wrong, but some are useful" (George Box). A model that included every possible variable would be useless. When we make a model we try to simplify the real situations by not including variables that make very little difference. The meaning of "very little" varies by field; and which variables you want to include will vary depending on what you are doing.
3. You have measurement error.

There are probably other reasons as well, but those are three big ones.